# how to find the object between two different dates in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am working on mongodb.I need to find the object between two dates.I stored date as a time stamp.My sample object is:

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("5a166be2509a93571c1546f4"),
 "project_id" : "5a1668b6509a93571c154509", 
"project_name" : "WORLD AIDS DAY",
"sex" : "MALE",
 "title" : "Apply for MTV promo", 
"creation_time" : "1511418850391", }
```

I need to find object between two dates.
I have tried using this but still not works:

```
db.collection.find({creation_time: {
$gte: new Date(1511418850391),
$lte: new Date(1521457316108)
}})
```

It does not display anything.Where i am doing wrong??

Comment: `"1511418850391"` is a string and not a Date.

Comment: ... so a `$gte: "1511418850391", $lte: "1521457316108"` might work. If you have dates before 2002, they may be a digit short and not sort nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
db.collection.find({creation_time: {$gte: "1511418850391",$lte: "1521457316108"}})
```